# Inverse Function Theorem: Proving Global Invertibility.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function-theorem

My question states: Prove that the following coordinate transformation is invertible everywhere, at all values of $(x, y)$ .

$$u = \arctan(x - y)$$

$$v = \sinh(3x) + 2\sinh(y)$$

That is x and y can be functions of both $u$ and $v$: (i.e. $x(u,v) = x, y(u,v) = y$ )

So, I say $$g(u,v) = (\arctan(x-y), \sinh(3x) + 2\sinh(y))$$ . The inverse function theorem says that g will be locally invertible near a specific point **a** iff its Jacobian Matrix, [Dg], is invertible at **a**.

So naturally, since I want to prove that $g(x,y)$ is invertible everywhere, I thought to show that [Dg] is invertible everywhere.

Since the Jacobian of $g(x,y)$ is a $2\times2$ matrix, it's clear that any matrix A equal to: \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
is not invertible if $ad = bc$.

So, since my Jacobian is the matrix of partial derivatives, A is equal to:

\begin{bmatrix}(1/(1+(x-y)^2)&-1/(1+(x-y)^2)\\3cosh(3x)&2cosh(y)\end{bmatrix}

I naturally set up $$ad = bc: 2\cosh(y)/(1+(x-y)^2) = -3\cosh(3x)/(1+(x-y)^2)$$which, by simple multiplication, yields:

$$2\cosh(y) = -3\cosh(3x).$$

Now I don't have any experience with hyperbolic cosine functions but graphing

$$2\cosh(y) = -3\cosh(3x)$$

yields no solutions, which would prove that $g(x,y)$ is invertible everywhere. Proving it is difficult, though.

My question is: how do I prove that the system $2\cosh(y) = -3\cosh(3x)$ has no solutions for any $(x,y)$?

My apologies for the lackluster formatting; I'm new to math stackexchange and don't know a ton of coding.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the definition of cosh:
$$ cosh(z) := \frac{e^{z}+e^{-z}}{2} > 0 \Rightarrow 2cosh(y)+3cosh(3x) > 0$$
The image of the exponential function is always greater zero. This contradicts:
$$\exists x,y \in \mathbb{R}:2cosh(y)=-3cosh(3x) \Leftrightarrow 2cosh(y)+3cosh(3x) =0 $$